# Why power bi generating different datasets with same name

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I am sending data from stream analytics to power bi. I have created 4 different outputs that are referencing same powerbi subscription and same dataset name but different table names.
I am writing to these outputs from stream analytics but on the power bi end I am getting different datasets with the same. The problem then is that I cannot run any joins on these tables as they are on different datasets.
I have even tried to write to same powerbi output from stream anaytics but it says that I cannot reuse same output in different statements.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Power BI output feature of Azure Stream Analytics has the limitation of 1 table per dataset. So, having multiple tables per dataset and joining them is not possible right now.

Comment: Hope to see that addition soon :)